# JQuery: filter text in ajax submition

Tags: jquery, regex

what's the better regex to filter text to be submited via form in order to block html text and javascript code?

Here's what I am using:

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
filter_input: function(options){
    var defaults = {
        regex:".*",
        live:false
    }
    var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
    var regex = new RegExp(options.regex);
    function filter_input_function(event){
        var key = event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : 0;
        // 8 = backspace, 9 = tab, 13 = enter, 35 = end, 36 = home, 37 = left, 39 = right, 46 = delete
        if (key==8 || key==9 || key==13 || key==35 || key==36|| key==37 || key==39 || key==46){
            if ($.browser.mozilla){
                if (event.charCode==0 && event.keyCode==key){ return true; }
            }
        }
        var string = String.fromCharCode(key);
        if (regex.test(string)){ return true; }
        return false;
    } if (options.live){
        $(this).live('keypress', filter_input_function);
    } else {
        return this.each(function(){
            var input = $(this);
            input.unbind('keypress').keypress(filter_input_function);
        });
    }
}
});
    //$('textarea').filter_input({regex:'[a-zA-Z0-9_ ()\+\-$&%@.,!;?]', live:true});
    $('textarea').filter_input({regex:'[a-zA-Z0-9]',live:true});

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is never a 100% secure solution, so don't rely on it. You must have server-side filters to ensure your data.

Anyway, if you want to filter the data in javascript, and you want to reject the html tags, you can accept all the chars but '<' and '>'.

Comment: Sure, but I wish to make this first filter.